# 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable after 2nd run in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, computer-vision, jupyter-notebook

Very simple code. Everything worked fine. I put hls_binary and gradx into the method of comb_binary.

```
image = mpimg.imread('test_images/test4.jpg')
comb_binary = comb_binary(image)
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(28,16))
ax1.imshow(image2)
ax1.set_title('A', fontsize=20)
ax2.imshow(comb_binary, cmap = 'gray')
ax2.set_title('B', fontsize=20)
```

But, If I re-run that cell in notebook, I will run into this Error:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

1st time. It works:
[image]

Run that cell again:
[image]

Here are the definition of all method just in case:

```
def abs_sobel_thresh(img, orient, sobel_kernel, thresh):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    if orient == 'x':
        sobel = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0)
    else:
        sobel = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1)
    abs_sobel = np.absolute(sobel)
    scaled_sobel = np.uint8(255*abs_sobel/np.max(abs_sobel))
    grad_binary = np.zeros_like(scaled_sobel)
    grad_binary[(scaled_sobel >= thresh[0]) & (scaled_sobel <= thresh[1])] = 1
    return grad_binary

def hls_select(img, thresh):
    hls = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HLS)
    s_channel = hls[:,:,2]
    hls_binary = np.zeros_like(s_channel)
    hls_binary[(s_channel > thresh[0]) & (s_channel <= thresh[1])] = 1
    return hls_binary

def comb_binary(image):
    gradx = abs_sobel_thresh(image, orient='x', sobel_kernel=9, thresh=(20, 100))
    hls_binary = hls_select(image, thresh=(170, 255))
    combined_binary_final = np.zeros_like(gradx)
    combined_binary_final[(hls_binary == 1 ) | (gradx == 1)] = 1
    return combined_binary_final
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you evaluate a cell in jupyter, it runs those commands in the environment that has been built from the previous commands.  So, when you have a line like:

```
comb_binary = comb_binary(image)
```

The first time everything is good.  You just replace `comb_binary` (the function) with it's result.  Now `comb_binary` is a numpy array ... However, if you try to execute the cell again, `comb_binary` is now a numpy array -- not a function.  It's the same as if you had written:

```
comb_binary = comb_binary(image)
comb_binary = comb_binary(image)
```

And you wouldn't expect *that* to work out in most cases ;-).

Comment: Oh, how stupid I am. Sorry, new to software. So, I guess I need to use some different variable name to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Patrick -- Don't worry about it.  This stuff happens to all of us.  I've run into this problem with LONG jupyter documents where I re-use a name that was defined ages ago ...  It _is_ a bit confusing because you don't _see_ the previous lines of code right there.